# Geocore - TPL and PHP Files (Smarty)

Tags: php, smarty

I'm using Geocore to develop a site.

In assigning templates for a specific page, we have a .tpl file for that.
This is to separate the business logic with the template (front-end), blah.. etc.
I already have basic knowledge on how to include php variables in the .tpl file using the smarty syntax. The problem is, how do I assign a .php file so that the variables can be read in the template(.tpl)?

Comment: You pass them via smarty's `assign()` method

Comment: then, i could already call the variable in any tpl files?

Comment: that depends on how you define "any"

Comment: sorry, i can't just seem to picture it all out. Where should i put my .php files? in the template folder in geocore?

Comment: I don't even know what is geocore, I've just said how to pass a variable from an arbitrary php to an arbitrary template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "assign" a PHP file to a template. That relationship works the other way around: from within a given PHP file, you call a specific template to be used for rendering its contents. You can assign individual variables to that template via smarty's `assign()`, from inside the PHP file that uses it.

If you need to create an interface between an entire PHP file and a given template, your best bet is to create a custom Smarty plugin, per http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl. GeoCore has several built-in plugins that might help get you started: take a look in the `/classes/geo_smarty_plugins/` directory

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about already existing .tpl files found in geoCore. A particular .tpl file would be called by an already existing .php file. If you need to pass a new smarty variable to the .tpl file you need to find out which PHP file calls the .tpl file and then  add the new variable to THAT particular PHP file.